# setOnFocusChangeListener change backgroundcolor

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to make it so when the user focuses on a text view the background changes colour and then when it looses focus the textview looses the focus colour.  Can you please help?

```
TextView tv1=new TextView(this);

tv1.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {

        if(hasFocus){
            v.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
        }else{
            v.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        }

    }

});
```

Comment: why don't you use xml for that?

Comment: because it is getting added dynamically with lots of text views

Comment: The background is not changing color

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To default textView are not clickable and focusable, then you need to set it.

Try this.

```
tv1.setClickable(true);
tv1.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is OK, the only problem is the first line **new TextView(this)** is not the best way to create a TextView, first create it in an xml and from your java code call it like this:

```
EditText tv1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.my_textViewId);
```

The rest of your code works great.

Hope it helps.